# apend a letter to the end of particular strings

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I have

```
str.replace(/w1/, "w1"+c).replace(/w2/, "w2"+c) ... .replace(/wn/, "wn"+c);
```

where `wn` are the instances i want to append `c` to and `str` is some entered string.

i thought of something like this

```
str.replace(/w1|w2...wn)/, "str"+c);
```

but that returns *all* of the string with the added `c`

e.g.

```
var str = "foo";
str.replace(/foo|bar/, str+"something");
// -> "foosomething"
//but for
var str = "hello foo";
// -> "hello hello foosomething"
//which repeats all of the string, the problem
```

so my question is:
how can i append a character to the end of certain strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture what you are replacing so you can use the captured value in the replacement:

```
var str = "w1";
var c = "foo";
var replaced = str.replace(/w([0-9]+)/g, '$1'+c);
// output 1foo
```

If you want to match the entire w*n* string, the just change the regex to:

`str.replace(/(w[0-9]+)/, '$1'+c);`

Which will output `w1foo`

Comment: You might want to add the global flag to the regexes also.

Comment: the `w1`,`w2` etc. were kind of just place holders. this is great though, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, hopefully the capture groups and the variables they produce get you up and running

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) and [substitution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in your replacement operation to append strings to matches. Make note of the `()` parentheses and `$1` parameter here:

```
str.replace(/(w1|w2)/, '$1'+c)
```